# ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=android exited with exit code 127

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am about to build my first mobile app and then build it to android studio and turn it into apk. but every time I build it, it sets just like this.

I've reinstalled everything. I am using nvs. for Windows.

these are my specifications

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "10.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

ionic version
5.4.16
npm -v
8.3.1
cordova -v
11.0.0
node -v
v16.14.0

is there any way that I can resolve this issue? also when I look at the logs. this shows me:

> [error] Error: Project target does not exist.
> at findProjectTarget (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:49:15)
> at Object.getBuilderName (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:62:46)
> at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:101:35)
> at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:242:55)
> at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:295:35)
> at RunCommand.run (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js:15:25)
> at RunCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command.js:136:33)
> at async runCommand (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:224:24)
> at async default_1 (C:\Users\Fatboi\proj\StayWeather\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:70:31)